# Reference number of invitation before booking a flight to iran

Tags: visas, iran, german-citizens, invitation-letters

We (2 Germans) are about to visit Iran in February and want to cross the border coming from Armenia. We don't have a reference number yet. This reference number is needed for getting a visa. You can get this reference code by a travel agency or a Iranian host gets you this number. I've heard, that you need the reference code before booking the flight. We have booked the flight already. Is this a problem?

Comment: Reference number of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference number you're referring to, is issued by the Iranian Ministry of Foreign Affairs to visa applicants.

It is mandatory to get one prior to being issued a visa, but you do not need one to book a flight, or even to board your flight. The airline generally will not look for it, since they will [see in Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=IR&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=00&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C) that you are eligible for a visa on arrival.

It's [not mandatory](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/middle-east/iran/iran-visa-on-arrival-experience-january-2014) to have a reference number if you wish to obtain a visa on arrival, but it will make the visa-on-arrival process [much faster](http://www.iranembassy.org.au/english_AU/council/airportvisa.aspx) if you have a reference number.

Note that visas on arrival can only be obtained at the major airports in Iran. You can't obtain a visa on arrival if you enter via land, and will need a regular visa in this case.